# Negligence of psychiatrist

Tags: medical, mental-health

What percentage of patients who attempted to sue their psychiatrist for negligence have succeeded?

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to find "negligence" stats rather than medical malpractice stats, and harder to find stats specific to psychiatry, but this is what I found.

- "Physicians win 80% to 90% of the jury trials with weak evidence of medical negligence, approximately 70% of the borderline cases, and even 50% of the trials in cases with strong evidence of medical negligence."<sup>1</sup>
- "The chances of a patient winning a medical malpractice lawsuit against a doctor in Canada are slim [...] From 2005 to 2010, only 4,524 lawsuits were filed against Canadian doctors. During that five-year period, 3,089 claims were dismissed or abandoned [...] out of 521 cases that went to trial, only 116 led to a judgment that favoured the patient. [...] Of more than 4,000 lawsuits filed against doctors from 2005 to 2010, only 2 per cent resulted in trial verdicts for the victim."<sup>2</sup>
- 2.6% of psychiatrists annually had a malpractice claim made against them. <sup>3</sup>

  [image]
- "Most payouts are due to settlements, not judgments. Ninety three percent of payouts made in 2012 were the result of a settlement. Only five percent were due to judgments, ..."<sup>4</sup>

#### References

<sup>1. Peters, P. G. (2009). [Twenty Years of Evidence on the Outcomes of Malpractice Claims. Clinical Orthopaedics and Related Research](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007%2Fs11999-008-0631-7), 467(2), 352–357.</sup>

<sup>2. Taylor, P. (2013). [Patients’ odds of winning medical malpractice suits in Canada aren’t good, says new book](http://www.theglobeandmail.com/life/health-and-fitness/health-navigator/patients-odds-of-winning-medical-malpractice-suits-in-canada-arent-good-says-new-book/article10812604/). The Globe and Mail.
Published Friday, Apr. 05, 2013</sup>

<sup>3. Jena, A. B., Seabury, S., Lakdawalla, D., & Chandra, A. (2011). Malpractice Risk According to Physician Specialty. The New England Journal of Medicine, 365(7), 629–636. http://doi.org/10.1056/NEJMsa1012370</sup>

<sup>4. Westgate, A. (2013). [Ten Notable Physician-related Malpractice Statistics](http://www.physicianspractice.com/blog/ten-notable-physician-related-malpractice-statistics). Physicians Practice.</sup>